# Keep soft keyboard open when enter key is pressed

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Well, I'm trying to prevent the soft keyboard from closing when the user press the "ok" button after editing a text field.
Actually, what i'm trying to achieve is : when "ok" button is pressed, the field is parsed and if valid, it starts another activity.
That is easy enough.

But, when the field is not valid, I want the soft keyboard to stay open.
And that's... a hell more complicated.
If anyone know how to achieve such a thing...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : what I mean by the OK button is the OK button from the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Attach [`OnEditorActionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html) to your text field and return `true` from its `onEditorAction` method, when *actionId* is equal to [IME_ACTION_DONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_DONE). This will prevent soft keyboard from hiding:

```
EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEdit);
txtEdit.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
      // your additional processing... 
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Depending on your EditText `android:imeOptions` value, you may need to check actionId against `IME_NULL`, `IME_ACTION_GO` etc.

Comment: Worked perfectly! been looking for this.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Idolon. My actionId == 66, but I couldn't find this constant in the EditorInfo class.

Comment: That will not work not on newer versions of android nor on emulator

Comment: @AlwaysConfused no wonder, it has been over 6 year since I posted this answer :). But thanks, for letting me know - I will check what was changed in the latest versions and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Idolon Hi, do you have any clue on how to keep the keyboard on? I couldn't find the "new" way.