# Android disable Enter key in soft keyboard

Tags: android, key, android-softkeyboard, enter

Can anyone tell me how to disable and enable the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in the soft keyboard?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would also like to know how to do this.  I've noticed in my phonegap application that if I use the enter key after completing entry into a text field that sometimes the screen does not render correctly.  If I use the native android back button when done it works perfect every time.

Answer (score 18):

just go to your xml and put this attribute in EditText

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

and your enter key will be gone

Comment: I don't know if this is what they were asking specifically but it's exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: android:singleLine is deprecated but it is working perfectly for this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Attach [OnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html) to your text field and return true from its `onEditorAction` method, when `actionId` is equal to [IME_ACTION_DONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_DONE). This will prevent soft keyboard from hiding:

```
EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEdit);
txtEdit.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
      // your additional processing... 
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Refer [this LINK.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202369/keep-soft-keyboard-open-when-enter-key-is-pressed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50460109/19856629

Answer (score 4):

Try this, together imeOptions = **actionDone**

```
<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/edittext_done"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:imeOptions="actionDone"
   android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `EditText's` layout put something like this:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,"
```

You can also enumerate the rest of the symbols that you would like to be able to enter there, but not the enter key.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is quite old but an easy way of disabling the enter key is to set android:maxLines="1" in your EditText.

Comment: downvoted, not working. I have an EditText with maxLines="1" and still shows and handles the enter key.