# how to have close option in android keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I don't wanna see the `Enter` option on my keyboard. showing `close` instead of `Enter` option. what should I do?

The screenshot of my layout:

[image]

my xml code :

```
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/value_charge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:maxLength="8"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my answer,
the answer is :

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:maxLines="1"
```

> [Android disable Enter key in soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271586/android-disable-enter-key-in-soft-keyboard)

Comment: your codes doesn't work but your link helped me , thanks