# Android: Prevent on-screen keyboard from hiding on Button click or on IME action

Tags: java, android, keyboard, show-hide, android-softkeyboard

By default, Android dismisses the on-screen keyboard when a user presses Send on the keyboard or clicks on a `Button` on the UI.  However, I am building a messaging app, and would like to keep the soft keyboard on the screen even if a user clicks Send or any other button on the UI.  This is the standard behavior for messaging apps (Facebook's messages functionality, for example, or Google Hangouts), so I know it can be done.

I have tried the [suggestions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202369/keep-soft-keyboard-open-when-enter-key-is-pressed) (returning `true` from the `onEditorAction` method of [`OnEditorActionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html)) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016430/prevent-buttons-from-hiding-soft-keyboard-on-android) (`InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED`).  The first seems to work on API 2.3, but was unsuccessful on 4.2.  The latter didn't work at all.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?