# How to prevent keyboard from dismissing on pressing submit key in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, submit, android-softkeyboard

I'm making a flutter application where user can type a message and hit send button IN THE KEYBOARD to send the message. The problem is when I press the send button the message gets send but the keyboard gets automatically dismissed. How can I prevent that from happening?
Thanks in advance.

```
TextField(
  autofocus: true,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
  decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
    hintText: "Let's talk",
    border: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1),
    ),
  ),
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
  onSubmitted: null,
)
```

Comment: Could you share the relevant code with us?

Comment: @RobinReiter have changed the **enter** key on keyboard to **send** key `textInputAction: TextInputAction.send`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**`TextField` widget has a parameter just for this purpose!**

While `onSubmit` callback can be used to handle business logic when the user presses done, there is also a property called `onEditingComplete`, specially made to handle focus-related logic. So you should use both, for better code readability.

According to the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onEditingComplete.html):

> The default implementation of onEditingComplete executes 2 different
> behaviors based on the situation:
>
> When a completion action is pressed, such as "done", "go", "send", or
> "search", the user's content is submitted to the controller and then
> focus is given up.
>
> When a non-completion action is pressed, such as "next" or "previous",
> the user's content is submitted to the controller, but focus is not
> given up because developers may want to immediately move focus to
> another input widget within onSubmitted.

Therefore, if you don't like this behaviour, for example, "send" is considered a "completion action" here, thus in an Instant Messaging (chatting) app, each time user sends a short message, the keyboard will be collapsed. But if we override the `onEditingComplete` callback to an empty function, it will stop the default behavior and not hide the keyboard.

**Sample code:**

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  onSubmitted: (value) {
    sendMessage(text);
    _controller.clear();
  },
  onEditingComplete: () {}, // this prevents keyboard from closing
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
)
```

**Demo:**

[image: demo gif]

For complete explanation and comparison between `onSubmitted` and `onEditingComplete` callbacks, check out [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65172300/1032613).

Comment: removing this line onEditingComplete: () {}, helped me.

Comment: what if you tap on the send icon?

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:-

First Create a `FocusNode` and assign it to your textfield, do the following :-

The `FocusNode` is a long lived component so initialize it in the `initState` method:-

```
FocusNode inputFieldNode;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    inputFieldNode = FocusNode();
  }
```

Do not forget to cleanup the `FocusNode` in `dispose` method after the Form is disposed:-

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    inputFieldNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Assign the `FocusNode` to the textfield and write the following code in `onSubmitted:`:-

```
TextField(
            focusNode: inputFieldNode,
            onSubmitted: (String) => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(inputFieldNode),
          )
```

Now the textfield will not lose focus even after pressing the submit button.

Answer (score 6):

The cleanest approach would be to use onEditingComplete() with TextEditingController instead of onSubmitted(text). Refer below example.

```
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  TextField(
       controller: _controller,
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
       textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
       placeholder: 'Type your message',
       onEditingComplete: (){
           if (_controller.text.isEmpty) return;

           sendMessage(_controller.text);
       },
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Focus node
FocusNode _myTextFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SafeArea(
   body: Focus(
     onFocusChange: (hasFocus) => !hasFocus ? _myTextFieldFocusNode.requestFocus() : null
     Container(
      child: // child goes here
     )
   ),
  );
}
```

If the user taps to something like it can  "dismiss the keyboard" **Focus() widget** will detect
changes and this is where you might want to put your _myTextFieldFocusNode.requestFocus()

keyboard won't have a chance to dismiss and reopen again

Answer (score 1):

```
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');
```

on onSubmit method

Comment: the onSubmit calls a method which sends the message in the text field

Comment: ^not clear . this answer will work try with in a setState or in onSubmit method do a new requestFocus

Comment: @BenjithKizhisseri isn't there some way to prevent text field from losing focus

Comment: but then i will have to call focus on text field every time i press send button