# Flutter: TextField difference between onEdittingComplete and onSubmitted

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to figure out the difference between `onEdittingComplete` and `onSubmitted`, I don't know when the latter should be used since the former can be used to switch focus or to submit the content of the form.

I tried looking into the documentation but there is not much said about the `onSubmitted` property.

Answer (score 50):

**onSubmitted**

As the name suggestions, it's called when user finishes editing, e.g. press "done" or "send" on the keyboard. The callback conveniently passes the value to you, so you can do your business logic with it. At the same time, since Flutter assumes the user is "done", it will hide the on-screen keyboard.

**onEditingComplete**

This is more of an "FYI" that tells you that the user has finished editing. It is fired **before** `onSubmitted`. It does not pass you the value (while you can technically get the value using a controller, that's not the intention here), because you can still handle value-related business logic in `onSubmitted`. Both events will fire anyway.

The real purpose behind `onEditingComplete` is that, in the default implementation, Flutter hides the on-screen keyboard when the keyboard action is
considered a "completion action", such as "done", "go", "send", or "search", but does not hide the keyboard if the action is "non-completion", such as "next" or "previous". (The keyboard action is specified in `TextField` widget's `textInputAction` property.)

If you don't like this behaviour, you can override it. For example, "send" is considered a "completion action" here, thus in an Instant Messaging (chatting) app, each time user sends a short message, the keyboard will be collapsed, that's not good. But if we override the `onEditingComplete` callback to an empty function, it will stop the default behaviour and not hide the keyboard. For example:

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  onSubmitted: (text) {
    sendMessage(text);
    _controller.clear();
  },
  onEditingComplete: () {}, // do not hide keyboard
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
)
```

Demo:

[image: demo gif]

Comment: there is also the onFieldSubmitted property

Comment: @Ced it's the same thing, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField/TextFormField.html#:~:text=onSubmitted%3A%20onFieldSubmitted

Answer (score 4):

**onSubmitted:**

```
final ValueChanged<String> onSubmitted
```

It returns the `TextField` entered value in `onSubmitted` callback, most of the time its used for next/previous field button of keyboard when using `TextInputAction.next` and `TextInputAction.previous` for `textInputAction` performed.

**onEditingComplete:**

```
final VoidCallback onEditingComplete
```

It's similar to `onSubmitted` but does not return value inside the callback, instead, it updates the text `controller` and then we can fetch a value from the `controller` where ever required.

Comment: *instead, it updates the text controller* isn't the controller auto-updated each time a character is entered or deleted?

Comment: I think textController do that, but onEditingComplete is some sort of callback mechanism which tell us that text editing is done and now we can use that value.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile, onEditingComplete is called before the keyboard closes and onSubmitted is called after.