# What is the difference between onSubmitted and onEditingComplete in Flutter textField widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter2.0, flutter-text, flutter-textinputfield, flutter-textformfield

What is the difference between `onSubmitted` vs `onEditingComplete` in Flutter `textField` widgets?

I mean, `onSubmitted` already passes us the value the user has entered which we can use when submitting is done. Why need an `onEditingComplete` property?

I also came across [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63690311/flutter-textfield-difference-between-onedittingcomplete-and-onsubmitted%20that%20discusses%20this%20topic.)

According to the top answer of this post, `onEditingComplete` is used to determine whether the keyboard should be hidden or kept after the user submits the data. If this is the case, why would flutter go leaps and bounds to have a property called `onEditingComplete` that **ACCEPTS A FUNCTION**? They could simply have a property like `hideKeyboardAfterEditing` which accepts either true or false.

(I might have understood the mention Stack Overflow post wrong here. But this is how my mind grasped it)

Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are technically the same but `onEditingComplete` will **not** lower the onscreen keyboard (example : chat apps) and `onSubmitted` will lower the onscreen keyboard and additionally `onSubmitted` will return the textfield value.

Comment: thank you for the response. One thing I would like to clarify from you is, in the top answer in the Stackoverflow post I have mentioned they mention `But if we override the onEditingComplete callback to an empty function, it will stop the default behaviour and not hide the keyboard.`. This implies that the soft keyboard is kept only if we pass an empty function to the `onEditingComplete` property. But your answer says that soft keyboard always stays. This seems to be a conflict to me.

Can you please clarify this for me? Thanks.

Comment: The `onSubmitted` will definitely shift focus to the next widget but `onEditingComplete` will behave in 2 ways based on the actions.
1. Completion action (send, go, submit) then focus is given up.
2. non completion action (next, previous) then focus is not given up.