# Keyboard should show always and should not minimize until i press back

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a chat feature in my application. everything is working fine. The problem i am facing is that i have an edittext and a button for sending the text. Now when i press the send button the keyboard comes down which i don't want. 
Because it is very annoying for the user to open the keyboard after sending every message. Does anyone have any solution for this. it is a very silly issue but it is quite important for me. and is there any change in xml or manifest which we can make which will help solve this problem

Comment: i dont know how but the issue got solved, there was a progressdialog which was shown when the button was pressed. i just commented the line and all the progressview from the class then the issue was solved. weird but true

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // User has pressed Back key. So hide the keyboard
        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getWindowToken(), 0);
        // TODO: Hide your view as you do it in your activity
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // Eat the event
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same thing in one of my project's. Try doing this to show keyboard

```
private void showKeyboard(){
    InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    yourEditText.requestFocus();
}
```

This makes the keyboard go down only when back is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224021/4924793).

```
EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEdit);
txtEdit.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
      // your additional processing... 
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

});
```

Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: I meant your code, not mine. I want to see your `Activity`. So I can better understand your situation.

Answer (score 0):

if you return `true` from your `onEditorAction` method, action is not going to be handled again. In this case you can return `true` to not hide keyboard when action is `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`.

Hope it will help !

Comment: it is not working. the code below i tried. but the keyboard still minimizes

Comment: you added.. android:imeOptions="actionDone" ? in XML for EditText?

Comment: yes i added it in the xml and i added the code as shown below by @Emzor

Comment: Please upload your XML + Activity code and give links for accessing them, after that I can help you with this. Because this solution should work. Please upload and let me know.